# How to use hg on Windows with SSH under bash/ubuntu?

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu, mercurial

I was hoping I could put this in my `mercurial.ini`:

```
[ui]
ssh = C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c ssh
```

Since `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c ssh` looks like it's working:

```
C:\Users\mpen>C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c ssh
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file] [-L address]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-Q query_option] [-R address] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] [user@]hostname [command]
```

But when I `hg pull` or `hg clone` it just hangs. Is there a trick to getting this to work, or am just not allowed to do cross-OS stuff like this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing its prompting for for user information. (eg. do you trust this host fingerprint)

Create a `run.bat` file:

```
bash -c "ssh %* 2>&1"
```

and add that to your ini file for ssh

```
[ui]
ssh = C:\somepath\run.bat
```

now when it hangs on hg clone - do a ctrl C, and you should get some text hinting where the problem is.